# Unusually low floating point accuracy when normalizing a vector

Tags: c++, vector, floating-point, normalize

I have a short method in my code to normalize a vector (actually a PCL point) which produces results of low accuracy. The code:

```
void normalize(pcl::PointXYZ::PointXYZ * p){
  float nf = 1/sqrt(p->x*p->x+p->y*p->y+p->z*p->z);
  //nf is a normalization factor precalculated to eliminate two FP divisions.
  p->x*=nf; p->y*=nf; p->z*=nf;
}
```

This function is passed the point with coordinates `(-0.850650787, 1.37638187, -0.525731087)`.  Debugging shows that `nf=0.587785244` after evaluation of the second line. When I do the same calculation in Mathematica, `nf=0.617708029`. This is an error of more than 5%! The coordinates of p are never greater than 2 or less than -2. Is this inaccuracy typical for these operations, or is there something wrong?

Comment: Irrelevant to your question, but note that `normalize(0)` is legal and crashes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to my calculations, `0.587785244` is the correct result (I get `0.5877852727698576` using Perl).  I suspect you're doing the calculation incorrectly in Mathematica.

Comment: Excel comes up with 0.587785272769858 as well, and as GMan pointed out, so does [Wolfram Alpha](http://tinyurl.com/3cfeezh).

Comment: @Bill: Heh, thanks. I gave up trying to link to it correctly.

Comment: @Gman: I think you could do it by using (i)(i) notation instead of i*i, but tinyurl solves it too.

Comment: Whoops, it looks like I entered the coordinates incorrectly into Mathematica to begin with. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You messed up the calculation in Mathematica. [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1/Sqrt%5B%28-0.850650787%29%5E2%2b1.37638187%5E2%2b%28-0.525731087%29%5E2%5D) gives the same result C does.